# Is it true that the book of Numbers has the exact same number of Hebrew letters as the book of Esther?

Tags: number, megillat-esther, bamidbar-numbers-book-of

I cannot remember the source and have been unable to find any further academic material, so I would like to put this request out to everyone in this online community.

I once heard that the book of Numbers has the exact same number of Hebrew letters as the book of Esther.

Is there any truth in this?

(I'm already aware that there are different versions of Esther, and its acrostic poems).

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 6):

This is incorrect by far, as anyone who read both can attest (observant Jews read the book of Esther at least twice every year on the Purim holiday and the book of Numbers at least once a year during the Spring/Summer period).

According to [TorahCalc](https://torahcalc.com/info/tanach-stats/)

- the book of Numbers has 63,529 letters
- the book of Esther has 12,111 letters

Comment: The Gemara Shabbos 116A says that Bamidbar is split into three sefarim. Perhaps one of the three match the number? https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.116a.2?lang=bi

Comment: This would not be true since Bamidbar and Naso alone already total over 16,000 letters even before getting to the split in Behaaloscha.

Comment: Leters in the Megilla vs words in...?

Comment: @MichaBerger that is very creative but the same source has 12,111 letters in Esther vs. 16,408 words in Bamidbar

Comment: @mbloch Thank you.